# Simulate "Enter" key press using IAccessible in Google Chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, visual-c++, iaccessible

I'm trying to create a QA automation for Google Chrome, in order to simulate URL navigation.
I got the correct object "Address and search bar" and also set the URL succesfully.

I can't figure out how to simulate the "Enter" key press after setting the URL.
I have tried *accDoDefaultAction* method but it is not supported by this object.

Any suggestions?

Thanks